# Set weekday to german in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, setlocale

I've go these simple MySQL Query:

```
$sql->setQuery("SELECT * FROM $db_table");

for ($i = 0; $i < $sql->getRows(); $i++) {
    $id   = $sql->getValue("id");
    $date = $sql->getValue("date");

    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');

    $date =  date('l, d.m.Y');

    echo $date;

    $sql->next();
}
```

The Output is: **Wednesday, 22.12.2016**.

Is there a way to get the weekday in german? I'm still using `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');`?!

Comment: Ermmmm `$date =  date('l, d.m.Y');` will actually print the system date by the way, not the date you got from the database

Answer (score 3):

It might be due to windows machine, locale `de_DE` is not detected. Instead use `deu_deu`. Also, use [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) that formats a local time/date according to locale settings:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
$date =  strftime('%A, %d.%m.%Y');
echo $date;
```

This prints:

```
Dienstag, 20.12.2016
```

You can see in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php#refsect1-function.setlocale-examples) for reference

---

**Update:** To display date from DB

```
$date =  strftime('%A, %d.%m.%Y', strtotime($date));
```

So your code will be:

```
$sql->setQuery("SELECT * FROM $db_table");

for($i=0;$i<$sql->getRows();$i++)
{

$id = $sql->getValue("id");
$date = $sql->getValue("date");

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
$date =  strftime('%A, %d.%m.%Y', strtotime($date));
echo $date;

$sql->next();
}
```

Comment: It print the current date but I've saved a date in the database. Is there a way to "connect" it?

Comment: @MarcusBauer Check updated answer! `$date =  strftime('%A, %d.%m.%Y', strtotime($date));`

Comment: Hmmm it was not really, busy checking facts on the locale codes for Germany and didnt see yours. So I deleted and UV's yours. I do hope we are both correct!

Comment: @RiggsFolly here is my ___sportsmanship___ award for you! Yes sometimes that happen, two people come with same answer but one beats the other in few secs :)

Answer (score 0):

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');